# Showing that $\bigcap_{i \in K}pr_i^{-1}(V_i) = \prod_{i \in I }V_i$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> Let $X = \prod_{i\in I}X_i$ be a product space with the product topology. Then $X$ has a basis consisting of elements of the form $U = \prod_{i \in I} V_i$ where $V_i \ne X_i$ for only finitely many $i$.

This is how the basis for the product topology is defined, but it can also be defined by the projection maps $pr_i : X \to X_i$ as $$\left\{\bigcap_{i \in K}pr_i^{-1}(V_i) \mid V_i \text{ open in } X_i, K \subset I \text{ finite}   \right\}$$

Now what I want to show is that $$\bigcap_{i \in K}pr_i^{-1}(V_i) = \prod_{i \in I }V_i$$ where the rhs satisfies that $V_i \ne X_i$ for only finitely many $i \in I$.

I know that $$pr_i^{-1}(V_i)=\{(x_1, \dots,x_i, \dots) \mid pr_i(x_1, \dots,x_i, \dots) =x_i \in V_i\} = X_1 \times \dots \times X_{i-1} \times U_i \times X_{i+1} \times \dots$$

So that $$\bigcap_{i \in K}pr_i^{-1}(V_i) = (V_1 \times X_2 \times \dots) \cap (X_1 \times V_2 \times \dots) \cap(X_1 \times X_2 \times V_3 \times \dots) \cap \dots$$

But I don't know if this rhs is same as $\prod_{i \in I}V_i$ because of the repitition of all the $X_i$'s and products?

Comment: $I$ needs not to be countable.

Comment: I know. I don't think I made that assumption anywhere? @psl2Z

Comment: you wrote $1,...,i-1,...$

Comment: Because $K \subset I$ is finite? @psl2Z

Comment: no, in $pr_i^{-1}(V_i)$ for example, you wrote $(x_1,...,x_i,..)$, implicitly assuming $I$ is countable. For the proof: try elementwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be precise, we have to show that
$$\bigcap_{i \in K}pr_i^{-1}(V_i) = \prod_{i \in I }V_i$$ where the rhs satisfies $V_i = X_i$ for $i \in I \setminus K$. Note that therefore $V_i \ne X_i$ is possible only for $i \in K$, i.e. only for finitely many $i$.

But we have $x = (x_i) \in \bigcap_{i \in K}pr_i^{-1}(V_i)$ iff $x_i = pr_i(x) \in V_i$ for $i \in K$ iff $x = (x_i) \in \prod_{i \in I }V_i$ where $V_i = X_i$ for $i \in I \setminus K$.

Comment: How do you get the last equivalence? Namely $$x_i = pr_i(x) \in V_i \text{ for } i \in K \iff x = (x_i) \in \prod_{i \in I }V_i$$ where $V_i = X_i$ for $i \in I \setminus K$

Comment: @SleepWalker For any collection of $M_i \subset X_i$ we have $x \in \prod_{i \in I} M_i$ iff $x_i \in M_i$ for all $i$. Thus $x_i \in V_i$ for $i \in K$ implies that $x_i \in V_i$ for all $i \in I$, where $V_i = X_i$ for $i \in I \setminus K$. Conversely, if all $x_i \in V_i$, then trivially $x_i \in V_i$ for all $i \in K$. The other indices do not play a role, whatever the $V_i$with $i \notin K$  may be.